# Client-Server arhitecture and communication protocols

Tags: android, ios, rest, client-server, rpc

I need to develop a client/server mobile app, but I don't know what to choose as a communication protocol between client and server. I know that there are REST architectural style and RPC.

1. What other architecture styles to communicate between client and
   server are?
2. What is the name of the architecture where server sends messages
   (with data) to the client and client handle them?
3. Can you please give me names of the books/articles/or any other
   information in this field? Maby some articles where is a comparation
   of client/server protocols.

   Thanks in advance.

Comment: They Are REST & SOAP Architecture ..
Client Side personally i use Spring for Android as REST Client.
Server Side it's depend to the language that you are using .. but still Http based manipulation ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only answer is HTTP, because simple and open win.

Variations on that theme - REST, SOAP, XML-RPC, etc. - only vary in the form the data takes on the wire.

HTTP is a request/response protocol.  The client requests data from the server and pulls it down.

HTML5 is adding web workers and sockets for push from server to client.  That has a publish/subscribe feel to it, because several clients can simultaneously receive a data payload from the server on its volition.

No book recommendations from me.